# How to create a nested RateLimiter with guava

Tags: java, guava

In my case, I have to create some rate limiter. 3 local rate limiter and 1 for globe rate limiter.

Is it possible to return the permit when fail to acquire on globe rate limiter.

In the blow logic, when localRateLimiter1 and localRateLimiter2 are fully acquire, localRateLimiter3 may always return false when tryAcquire();

```
RateLimiter localRateLimiter1 = RateLimiter.create(10.0);
RateLimiter localRateLimiter2 = RateLimiter.create(10.0);
RateLimiter localRateLimiter3 = RateLimiter.create(10.0);
RateLimiter globeRateLimiter = RateLimiter.create(20.0);
```

Comment: No, there is no way to return permits.

Comment: Should I need to use tryacquire with timeout but it still reseve a token on local limiter

Comment: Not sure what you'd hope that would accomplish?

Comment: There three service need to be flow controlled. Each of them have 10QPS, but all the service add together cannot higher than 20QPS.

Comment: Then you might as well just use `acquire()` on both rate limiters you need?

Comment: Those service are real time, it need to be timeout after 100ms and response fail.

Comment: Then acquire with timeout sounds right for you.